# How to create unique/multiple sessions that allow simultaneous answering of a Django-based survey?

Tags: python, django, session, userid

I am doing a survey with Django and everything runs fine. The only problem I get is when multiple respondents answer the survey simultaneously. Then, the current session, in which the user-data is stored, is being overwritten and some strange effects take place.

How can I create a unique session for every respondent so that more than one can answer the survey at the same time?

If the survey is answered by one person at a time, everything is fine.

Doesn't

```
user_id = random.randint(0,10000)
initial={user_id:request.session.get(user_id, None)}
```

create a unique session for every respondent to allow simultaneous answering? Somehow respondent 2 overwrites some data of respondent 1, if respondent 1 is still doing the survey and hasn't finished yet.
Thanks in advance!

```
def home(request):
               
                user_id = random.randint(0,10000)
                initial={user_id:request.session.get(user_id, None)}
                
                form = SurveyForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    # Save input data in session
                    if form.is_valid():
                        request.session['age'] = form.cleaned_data['age']
                        request.session['gender'] = form.cleaned_data['gender']
                        request.session['education'] = form.cleaned_data['education']
                        
                        return redirect('heat_tech_survey:InformationDCE')
                    else:
                        return render(request, 'heat_tech_survey/home.html', {'form': form})
                else:
                    return render(request, 'heat_tech_survey/home.html', {'form': form})

def RandomDCE(request):
                # Create independent Counters for every Choice Set, so people
                # can use the "Back-Button" in the Browser without increasing the counter
                # "count" for every website-reload in the function
                global count, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8   
                
                # Randomize the order of Choice Sets for each respondent
                if count == 0:
                    global number_list, number_list2, choiceblock
                    number_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
                    number_list2 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
                    random.shuffle(number_list)
                    random.shuffle(number_list2)
                    # Choose one of the 2 available Choice Blocks randomly
                    choiceblock=[0,1]
                    random.shuffle(choiceblock)
                    
                # Finish only when every Choice Set has been answered   
                if  C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5 + C6 + C7 + C8 == 8:
                    return redirect('heat_tech_survey:preferencequestions')
                
                # First Choice Block
                if choiceblock[0] == 0: 
                    count = C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5 + C6 + C7 + C8
                    x = number_list[count]
                    count = count + 1
                # Second Choice Block
                else:
                    count = C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5 + C6 + C7 + C8
                    x = number_list2[count]
                    count = count + 1
                
                # Redirect to the random order of Choice Sets
                return redirect('heat_tech_survey:home%d' % (x))
                return count
 
def home2(request):
                # Indicates to the respondents how many Choice Sets are answered
                context = count
                # Randomize the order of attributes in a Choice Set
                rand = [1,2,3,4,5]
                random.shuffle(rand)
                a = rand[0]
                b = rand[1]
                c = rand[2]
                d = rand[3]
                e = rand[4]
                
                initial={user_id:request.session.get(user_id, None)}
                form = SurveyFormDCE(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    form = SurveyFormDCE(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        # Individual counter to allow using the "Back-Button" in the Browser without increasing the a global counter
                        global C1
                        C1 = 1
                        # Save respondents' input
                        request.session['alternative1'] = form.cleaned_data['alternatives']
                        return redirect('heat_tech_survey:RandomDCE') 
                    else:
                        return render(request, 'heat_tech_survey/home2.html', {'form':form, 'context':context, 'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d, 'e':e})
                else:
                        return render(request, 'heat_tech_survey/home2.html', {'form':form, 'context':context, 'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d, 'e':e})

etc.
```

Comment: `random.randint` doesn't create a unique id. use `uuid` instead.https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, if random.randint creates 2 different ints, e.g. 111 and 333, shouldn't it still run properly? There must be another error I guess.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read. there is no explanation.

Comment: I am sorry for that. The main question is just that: How to enable multiple people to answer the survey at the same time when using request.session.   Right now, the answers overwrite each other as the people are answering it at the same time but I thought that with 

initial={user_id:request.session.get(user_id, None)}

I can create multiple sessions that dont overwrite each other.

Comment: You don't set the session in your code. Result of the `request.session.get(user_id, None)` will always be `None`. This is how you should do it: request.session["user_id"] = user_id. Now you can access the `user_id` when a new request from user is made to your server.

Comment: Thanks! Last question because I didn't understand all of it. If 2 people enter the server at the same time, does 
`user_id = random.randint(0,10000)`
 `request.session["user_id"] = user_id`
                
`initial={user_id:request.session.get(user_id, None)}`
`form = SurveyForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial)`
create 2 different sessions, so that they can both answer the survey and I can save their input using e.g. `request.session['age'] = form.cleaned_data['age']` for both?

Comment: the session is different for each user. a key is saved in the user's browser as a cookie and. you can get the session id like this: `request.session.session_key` and it will be unique too.